# Using a Genetic algorithm to evolve to a specified string

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

so im working on a genetic algorithm that is meant to converge on a specific string, this string is a flattened asccii art, im using a sequenceMatcher to find the ratio of how similar a given chromosone is to the answer as my fitness, the code is as below:

```
import random
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

GA="0001111000001100000100001000101100010000000010001100010011100111111000011101001000010"
print(len(GA))


# Hyper-parameter
no_pop = 10 # population size
no_sel = 5   # slect the best no_sel idnividuals
no_gen = 10
p_xo = .8  # crossover probabilty/rate
p_m = 0.05 # mutation probabilty/rate per bit


# 1 Step: Select representation
no_bit = 85 # number of bits



# Create the pop
pop = [] # population
for i in range(no_pop):
    pop.append(''.join(random.choice('01') for j in range(no_bit)))
    
pop

# convert bitstring into decimal number
def dec(chromosome):
    d = 0
    for i in range(len(chromosome)):
        if chromosome[i] == '1':
            d += 2**i
    return d

def fitness(chromosome):
    return SequenceMatcher(None,str(dec(chromosome)),str(dec(GA))).ratio()  #check similarity to answer

def one_point_crossover(chromosome_1, chromosome_2):
    cut = random.randint(1, no_bit-1) # randomy select cut point
    offspring = chromosome_1[0:cut] + chromosome_2[cut:]
    return offspring


def bit_flip_mutation(chromosome):
    mutation = ''
    for i in range(len(chromosome)):
        if random.random() < p_m:
            if chromosome[i] == '0':
                mutation += '1'
            else:
                mutation += '0'
        else:
            mutation += chromosome[i]

    return chromosome

for g in range(no_gen):
    fit = []
    for i in range(no_pop):
        fit.append(fitness(pop[i]))
        
    print('Gen' + str(g))
    print(pop)
    print(fit)
    
    index = sorted(range(len(fit)), key=lambda k: fit[k], reverse=True)
    
    pop_new = []
    for i in index[:no_sel]:
        pop_new.append(pop[i])
        
    for i in range(no_sel, no_pop):
        parent_1 = random.randint(0, no_sel-1)
        parent_2 = random.randint(0, no_sel-1)
        offspring = one_point_crossover(pop_new[parent_1], pop_new[parent_2])
        offspring = bit_flip_mutation(offspring)
        pop_new.append(offspring)
        
    pop = pop_new
   
fit = []
for i in range(no_pop):
    fit.append(fitness(pop[i]))

print('Gen' + str(g))
print(pop)
print(fit)
```

currently the algorthim doesnt achieve mpore than around 57% simmilarity to the actual answer. im confused as to why this is, any siggesttions on how to improve this would be great.

Comment: I think `no_pop` and `no_gen` hyper parameters are too small according to your problem space (2^85).

Comment: Are you confident that your main loop is selecting the most fit individuals?  The logic looks a bit convoluted (this should be a simple sort/slice IMO but you're going through a bunch of levels of indirection), and a subtle bug in there could easily prevent you from converging on a solution.

Comment: Also, you should not convert your number into decimal because it will definitely occur overflow. You can use BCD representation or just leave it with the binary representation that it is. (It doesn't make any difference because you are not reducing the problem space)

Comment: @MatinZivdar increasing these to 100, 100 helped, the similarity of the given solutions got to around 84.7% similarity

Comment: @Samwise i believe the logic is correct, there are no bugs that i can find in it